# Delta notation in Thermodynamics

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Assume we want to calculate the finite Enthalpy change for a process.
$$H=U+pV$$

$$\Delta H=\Delta U + \Delta(pV) $$

Everything clear so far, but I do not understand how my teacher consecutively expands $$\Delta (pV)$$

into

$$\Delta (pV) = V\Delta p + p \Delta V + \Delta p \Delta V$$

What is this $$\Delta$$ operator applied to pV at once actually called? How is this result derived mathematically? Why is $$\Delta(pV)$$ not just $$\Delta p\Delta V$$?

Comment: $\Delta x$ is change in $x$.

Comment: Yes, but how is the operator applied to a product and why does the result of applying it to a product look like the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a rectangle with sides of length $p$ and $V$. Extend side $p$ by a quantity $\Delta p$ and side $V$ by a quanity $\Delta V$. You'll get a new rectangle whose sides are length $p + \Delta p$ and $V + \Delta V$. The quantity $\Delta(pV)$ represents the difference in area between the two rectangles.

Comment: So the three parts are actually the areas of the three sub-rectangles that extend the original area.. that makes perfect sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$\Delta(pV)=(p+\Delta p)(V+\Delta V)-pV=p\Delta V+V\Delta p +\Delta p\Delta V$$